# Create two windows

Tags: qt

could you some one give me an example meet following requirements:

1. one application with two windows/forms, they can cover each other, they are not parent/child relation.
2. one window has a button to pop up a message box like using
   `QMessageBox::information(this, tr("HELLO"), tr("WORLD"));`
3. when message box popped up, the another window still can move and drag.

I tried couples of way, all fail, could someone give me an example?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with QMdiArea? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html

Comment: You could show a "window modal" message box instead of the default, which is "application modal". See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#setWindowModality

Answer (score 0):

> One application with two windows/forms, they can cover each other,
>   they are not parent/child relation. How can we do that?

With Qt Creator generated widget-based app main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w1; // very simplistic
    w1.show();     // demo    
    MainWindow w2; // for two main independent
    w2.show();     // windows in Qt

    // help show windows apart
    w2.move(w1.geometry().left() + 50,
            w1.geometry().top() + 50);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Of course that can be done in many ways and I have similar approach in one of my apps. Mind that the app will only quit after you either explicitly close both 'main' windows or you can overload the [QWidget::closeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) for both of them and do [qApp->quit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) from there. So, that MainWindow generated class becomes MyMainWindow class with new event handler there. Also mind you get more than one task bar entry in Windows (also solvable but not answering this question).

And you have also received a good comment for:

> One window has a button to pop up a message box like using
>   QMessageBox::information(this, tr("HELLO"), tr("WORLD"));
>
> When message box popped up, the another window still can move and
>   drag. How can we do that?

[QMessageBox::setWindowModality](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#setWindowModality) should help.

Comment: QMessageBox::setWindowModality make the dialog is non-modal, the result what I want is dialog block one window, for another window can still drag and move

Comment: Try to pass the main window pointer as parent to QMessageBox and do show() not exec();.